# Re attaching options that were removed using jquery detach()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove options from a drop down based on what the user selects in a different dropdown.  If the user changes the causal dropdown, I need to re add the items in the effected dropdown.  I found the jquery detach() selector and I was able to remove the options.  Is there a way to re add the options that were previously removed? Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

```
function RemoveATD() {
...

    if (reason == '10' || reason == '11')
    {
        $("#ddlOverride option").each(function () {
            if (!(parseInt($(this).val()) === 0 || parseInt($(this).val()) === 15077 || parseInt($(this).val()) === 20660)) {
                $(this).detach();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#ddlOverride option").each(function () {
            $("#ddlOverride").append($(this));
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.detach()` returns the removed elements, so you can just store them in an array:

```
var arr = [];
if (reason == '10' || reason == '11')
    {
        $("#ddlOverride option").each(function () {
            if (!(parseInt($(this).val()) === 0 || parseInt($(this).val()) === 15077 || parseInt($(this).val()) === 20660)) {
                arr.push($(this).detach());
            }
        });
    }
```

and then later readd them:

```
for(el in arr){
    $('#ddlOverride').append(arr[el]);
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wen6ejqm/1/)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean re-add all the removed options, just save them somewhere not visible.

e.g. a hidden `select` like:

```
<select id="hidden" style="display: none"></div>
```

change your code to append them to the hidden select when detached:

```
if (reason == '10' || reason == '11')
{
    $("#ddlOverride option").each(function () {
        if (!(parseInt($(this).val()) === 0 || parseInt($(this).val()) === 15077 || parseInt($(this).val()) === 20660)) {
            // Store it (e.g. in a hidden select)
            $('#hidden').append($(this).detach());
        }
    });
}
else {
    $("#ddlOverride option").each(function () {
        $("#ddlOverride").append($(this));
    });
```

Note: you do not need to detach if you append it elsewhere (as it is moved in the DOM), so you can reduce it to:

```
  $('#hidden').append($(this));
```

To restore them simply append the stored child elements:

```
$("#ddlOverride").append($('#hidden').children());
```